# modsecurity bruteforce detection distinguishes between browsers

Tags: apache, brute-force, mod-security

I have modsecurity on my system that is set up to do brute force detection and IP-Adress blocking like this:

```
#Limit the login attempts comming from one ip
SecRule ip:bf_block "@gt 0" "deny,status:401,log,msg:'Too many login attempts from one ip!',id:10010"
# Setup Tracking. On a successful login, a 302 redirect is performed, a 200 indicates login failed.
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@streq /usermgmt/identityprovider/Account/Login" "phase:5,chain,id:10011,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0"
  SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^302" t:none
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@streq /usermgmt/identityprovider/Account/Login" "phase:5,chain,t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=+1,chain,id:10012"
  SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^200" t:none
SecRule ip:bf_counter "@gt 1" "t:none,setvar:ip.bf_block=1,expirevar:ip.bf_block=3600,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0,id:10013"
```

If I go to my login-page under /usermgmt/identityprovider/account/login with two browsers, one is edge and one is chrome; Screenshot:
[image: Two browsers opened with, one is edge and one chrome]
I try login on the left one with wrong credentials once:
[image: Tried login once in the edge-browser with wrong credentials, got to the login page with a warning]
If I try login with wrong credentials to the left browser for the second time, I get this that I expect:
[image: Tried login with wrong credentials to the left browser twice]
Now I try login with wrong credentials once on the right browser and I get this, which I dont expect. I expected to receive the same message as on the left after the first attempt. I should even get the message when I just reload the page, but I didn't:
[image: Tried login in chrome once, did not receive the error-page that was expected but can try login again]
Only if I try login again at the browser to the right I receive this page:
[image: Tried login in chrome the second time and received the error message]

It seems the settings for modsecurity bf-blocking dont't work on IP-adresses alone but rather on ports as well maybe? I am very unsure and I dont know how to configure it correctly since I'm having a hard time finding a documentation for this which explains this thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is advanced ModSecurity usage and ModSec is not necessarily the best tool for this.

What I do not see in your example is the initalization of the IP "collection" that you use to save your data.

It is also very hard to read your example, since it is badly formatted leading to rule 10012 carrying two chain actions, etc.

The only place where this is really documented properly is in the ModSecurity Handbook AFAICS.

If you do not want to buy this, then set all your rules to "log" and add a message that prints the value of the counter. And then debug.

This could easily take a pro 1-2 hours to debug. So expect some time to get this working. Advanced ModSecurity usage can be very painful.

Just my 2 cents.

-- OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set project dev-on-duty